# How to get the two month before now time?

Tags: mysql

i will use **DATE_ADD**,now if i want to get a rand time from 2012-10-1 to now,how should i do? time format: 2012-12-01 00:32:01

```
   created=DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD(
         NOW(), 
         INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
         INTERVAL 11*RAND() MONTH),
         INTERVAL 30*RAND() DAY),
         INTERVAL 23*RAND() HOUR),
         INTERVAL 59*RAND() MINUTE),
         INTERVAL 60*RAND() SECOND)
```

when i use the above code ,it get time isn't what i want. thank you.how to correct it?

eg: `30*RAND(3)`   what's the value will be?

Comment: what do you want? cant understand. Please provide an output so that it is easy to understand

Comment: get a rand created time between 2012-10-1 and now.

Comment: what is the structure of your table? Any sample data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-01') + (RAND() * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-01'))), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')`

Should do it, I suppose.

Functions can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SET @MIN = '2010-04-30 14:53:27';
SET @MAX = '2012-04-30 14:53:27';
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @MIN, @MAX)), @MIN);
```